# Detecting USB connection automatically in a network

Tags: networking, usb, script, usb-storage

I am having one network in my home (10 machines) with all machines are configured with Windows XP.

I want to get an automatic log from all users in the network if anybody access their USB drive.

I want get the log if some one just connected to the USB drive also(even though they haven't done any thing with that - file copy paste etc)

This is to test/ensure the security in the system.

Can anybody give me the list of softwares which could automatically perform this task or is it possible to write a script or program (in C language) that automatically does this?

From one of my friend , i heard that in their company they are following that and that running as a back ground process so he can't able to fetch that process name (without admin privilege).

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Sanctuary Device Control](http://securewave.creativerge.net/products.html) seems to be popular, I've certainly encountered it at a number of places.  Never experienced any of the others though.